# Can Multidimensional Hash Values be inserted into InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

In InfluxDB, can you post multidimensional hash values to the database?

For example, this hash:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": {
        "field2a": "value2a",
        "field3a": "value3a"
    }
}
```

If you can, how do you do this? When I try via the http admin interface, it neither errors out or returns success.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional values are not supported by InfluxDB.  Points have fields that are a set of key-value pairs.  Currently, values can only be of type float, integer, boolean, or string.  InfluxDB has no concept of nested key-values.  The relevant source is [here](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/blob/master/database.go#L794).

A workaround would be to store the JSON as a string literal by escaping all double quote characters (e.g. `\"`).  Then implementing whatever functionality required in the client.

```
curl -h -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write' -d '
{
    "database": "test",
        "retentionPolicy": "default",
        "points": [
            {
                "name": "json_blob",
                "tags": {
                    "tag1": "tag-value-a",
                    "tag2": "tag-value-b"
                },
                "fields": {
                    "value": "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":{\"field2a\":\"value2a\",\"field3a\":"value3a\"}}"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to use any of those fields for generating queries against InfluxDB right?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways yes, thats what I'm dealing with too, did you find a way to deal with relational data, stored in a string format like the above answer?